# Can't change sender address/domain in sendmail

Tags: sendmail, hostname

I have a server with sendmail and I need to send email througt PHP. I have an internal SMTP server on the same subnet, so I configured sendmail with `FEATURE(`nullclient', `mail.server.local')dnl` where mail.server.local is solved with an internal IP in `/etc/hosts`

There is no way that I can change the `from` address and domain. It's always `root@nameoftheserver.localhost.localdomain.`

```
Mar 20 16:18:48 nameoftheserver sm-mta[16402]: v2KFImVi016402: from=<www-data@nameoftheserver.localdomain.local>, size=406, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201703201518.v2KFImVD016401@nameoftheserver.localdomain.local>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
```

The output of  `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

```
      (short domain name) $w = nameoftheserver  
  (canonical domain name) $j = nameoftheserver.localdomain.local  
         (subdomain name) $m = localdomain.local  
              (node name) $k = nameoftheserver
```

How I can change this values?

Comment: Where do you see `root@localhost.localdomain`? Your next log line instead shows `www-data@nameoftheserver.localdomain.local`

Comment: root@ it's in the log if I send from the cli using php, www-data is from the browser. I need to change that. I modified the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you are trying to **change the envelope sender** (as PHP's `mail()` function already handles the "From:" address) with Sendmail. That can be achieved by building a *genericstable* database to map the input sender address to the address desired.

1. Create a text file `/etc/mail/genericstable` containing the mappings,

   ```
   www-data       desired.site.address@example.com
   root           root@example.com
   ```

   where the first value is the original username and the second value is the address desired. Or, if this doesn't work with your node server, the original sender address can also be in format

   ```
   www-data@nameoftheserver.localdomain.local  desired.site.address@example.com
   ```
2. Create another file `/etc/mail/generics-domains` containing the domains, separated by newline.
   (Notice, that the file MUST include your server's canonical domain name.)
3. Add the corresponding statements to `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

   ```
   FEATURE(`genericstable',`hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable.db')dnl
   GENERICS_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/generics-domains')dnl
   ```
4. Do the normal procedures after re-configuring Sendmail, e.g.

   ```
   cd /etc/mail
   /usr/bin/make
   /usr/bin/newaliases
   systemctl restart sendmail.service
   ```

Comment: didn't workI did it but did not work

Comment: Update: forget about my previous message, your solution resolve the problem! Many thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome! I didn't care to reply earlier because the comment didn't add any new information (i.e. error messages or logs) and the solution actually should have worked.